# Extract content from file in base64

Tags: python-3.x

My script reads from a web service (JSON) that returns me files (PDF, Excel, Word) in base64.  I need to extract the content to put into an Elastic Search.  What is the best library to do this?  Is there any way to do this without having to save the file to disk?

Comment: Could you show us some sample data?